# Property initialization before constructor execution

Tags: c#, constructor, object-initializers

I am using an object initializer to create an object with a `Position` property like this:

```
var control = new HtmlTextbox(browser)
{
    Position = position;
};
```

As I know it's the same as:

```
var control = new HtmlTextbox(browser);
control.Position = position;
```

But I want to use initializated `Position` property in my constructor method.
Is there any way to do it without providing the `Position` as an argument for constructor?

Comment: No, there isn't. But if `Position` is so important for the initialization process you should provide a constructor that takes it anyway.

Comment: How would you intend to take the code you know it is transformed into, `var control = new HtmlTextbox(browser);
control.Position = position;` and use the position in the constructor?

Comment: "_But I want to use initializated Position property in my constructor method_" ... Sorry didn't understand what you said at all

Comment: If you need the information available to the constructor, then *pass it into the constructor as an argument*. It doesn't make sense any other way.

Comment: @Servy I'm intrested if there is any ways to force constructor to set property value without puting that value into constructor paremeters.

Comment: @yolosora How do you expect the constructor to set a value when it isn't provided the value to be set?

Comment: if the value for position is a readonly or const, you can set the class Position member to that value in the constructor, or just use the literal value in the constructor, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @Servy by magic!! >:D

Comment: @stackuser83 You cannot in fact set a `const` variable in a constructor.  You can only ever assign it when declaring the variable.  That's what it means for it to be constant.

Comment: @Servy: You can let the constructor see other data, but only if you have something global / static for it to see. You could set a public static property on the class from the outside, for example, before invoking the constructor, then read that. But that's pretty horrible...

Comment: @yolosora: what you want is possible, but only once. It's the default value

Comment: @Servy also consider things like static globals, depending on situation needs

Comment: @TimSchmelter yeah, i was using the default value before, but in some cases it provided wierd behaviour, so i wanted to make opportunity for  setting  propery value without global changes in my classes. Well, looks like that's impossible :(

Comment: @Servy you can declare a local scope variable as a const in a class constructor

Comment: Looks like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is your ultimate goal here?

Comment: @stackuser83 Yes, you can, but you could never assign the value of a variable to said local.

Answer (score 5):

What you want to achieve is not possible.

It seems to me you want to make some parameters to the constructor optional. You may want to look into this pattern:

```
//Your constructor
public HtmlTextbox(TextboxConfiguration config)
{
    //config.Position
}

//A Transfer class
public class TextboxConfiguration
{
    public T Browser { get; set; }
    public T Position { get; set; }
}

//Your code
var config = new TextboxConfiguration
{
    Browser = browser;
    Position = position;
}
var textbox = new HtmlTextbox(config);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can approach this is using inheritance and initialize the value from there, as the most-derived class' constructor gets called last, but its values are initialized first.